# how to make card with more detail

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, human-interface-guideline, cards

How can I display all the information on this blood donation request card without cluttering the card's visibility on Stack UX? Additionally, I have a long text that describes the user's blood need, possibly around 200 letters. Please suggest a way to avoid filling the card with too much information while still conveying the necessary details.

[image]

Comment: Hire a graphic designer

Comment: Are all those pieces of information needed at that point in time of the user journey? Tell us a bit about the context.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, centered on creating good design, is a challenging one to answer succinctly. Design involves a combination of extensive knowledge and practical experience. I believe a good starting point for you might be exploring mood boards or sources of inspiration. I've attached a few examples of similar cards below that you might consider incorporating into your design.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Muhammadoufi feel free to  upvote the answer you found useful, not only mention it as comments, please,  -  see https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score -1):

Title and on the other end arrow for some kind of accordion/dropdown when you expand it you have rest of the info